# Failed to open stream when uploading file via ajax

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I have a laravel app in production DigitalOcean VPS with ubuntu and LEMP , web works perfectly but it seems I can't upload files from my web, when I try to upload image via ajax I get the following error (only in production, local works right):

```
message fopen(/var/www/luisaldada.com/public/uploads/file-25-05-2019-21-39-MAL-421.jpeg): failed to open stream: Permission denied
exception   ErrorException
file    /var/www/luisaldada.com/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapter/Local.php
line    158
```

This looks like an obvious permission error but I already gave write perm recursively  to laravel storage folder, I'm using laravel public/local disk to upload files into an upload folder inside public.

filesystems config file:

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Maybe it has something to do with public folder not having correct permissions to upload/write?

This are my permisions for laravel folder, as you can see I have gone as far as to set ACL for storage folder.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB1cj.png

This is how I upload file in contrller just in case:

```
$file = $request->file($name);
        $filename = 'file-'.Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y-H-i').'-'.str_random(3).'-'.mt_rand('000','999').'.'.$file->extension();
        $file->storeAs('uploads', $filename);
```

Comment: Error message seems to indicate you're trying to save to the `uploads` folder, not the `storage` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Okk, after checking uploads folder perms inside public they were: rwx r-x --x, I did a chmod 770 to uploads and now everything works, what do you guys think, I hope I didn't do anything risky.

I want to show you guys the commands I now use fot setting perms so you can give me your thoughs:

```
cd /var/www/luisaldada.com
sudo chown GabotronES:ww-data /var/www/luisaldada.com
&&
find /var/www/luisaldada.com -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
&&
find /var/www/luisaldada.com -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
&&
chmod 770 /var/www/luisaldada.com/public/uploads
&&
setfacl -Rdm u:www-data:rwx,u:GabotronES:rwx storage bootstrap/cache
&&
setfacl -Rm u:www-data:rwx,u:GabotronES:rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```